# Parsing HTTP requests with C

Tags: c, regex, http, parsing

I need to parse a HTTP request in C. I've been previously using std::regex for C++ but now I have to use C. What would be the best method to parse a HTTP request with C?

Comment: Did you consider instead to use a full HTTP server library, like https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache recommends cgic, you can find it at http://www.boutell.com/cgic/ and its very simple to use

Answer (score 1):

Several projects have used [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/), a state machine generator, to implement HTTP parsers in C. It is well suited to automating the kind of state machines you will need to build to parse HTTP, without the complexity of a parser generator like Bison.

Answer (score 0):

This is (of course) highly subjective, since you don't say what criteria you want to optimize.

If you're in POSIX-land, you can continue to use regular expressions, using `<regex.h>` quite easily. You can of course also hand-build a parser, use an existing library, or roll your own using e.g. [Bison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison).

Comment: Sadly I'm on Windows but I'd like it to work on multiple platforms.